# Replace value using previous row depending on condition (using a function such as sapply)

Tags: r, dataset, apply, sapply

I've got a large dataset so I'm trying to find a way to do this efficiently.

Going through the rows in a given column I want to take a particular condition and if it triggers I want to replace the current element with the value in the element above

For my code that condition is dependent on the element being == 2

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1   32
[3,]    2 4351
[4,]    2    1
[5,]    3    4
[6,]    4    5
[7,]    5 6546
[8,]   67  456
```

Should become

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1   32
[3,]    1 4351
[4,]    1    1
[5,]    3    4
[6,]    4    5
[7,]    5 6546
[8,]   67  456
```

But at the moment it becomes this (note that it changes all values simultaneously using sapply, so having 2 consecutive 2s will make it copy the 2 above)

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1   32
[3,]    1 4351
[4,]    2    1
[5,]    3    4
[6,]    4    5
[7,]    5 6546
[8,]   67  456
```

This is my current code with the same made up example:

```
rowid = 1

letable = cbind(c(1,3,4,5,67,2,2,1),c(1,4,5,6546,456,4351,1,32))

sortedtable =letable[order(letable[,1]),]


print(sortedtable)

abovefunction <- function(x){
  print(paste("this is x",x))
  if(x==2){ 
    print(x);
    value=sortedtable[rowid-1,1];
    print(paste("if ",x));
    rowid <<- rowid+1;
    print(rowid)
  }

  else{
    print(x);
    value = sortedtable[rowid,1];
    print(paste("else ",x));
    rowid <<- rowid+1; 
    print(rowid)
  }
  return(value)
}

sortedcolumn = sapply(sortedtable[,1], abovefunction)
print(sortedcolumn)
```

Is there a way can I do this function/replacement in sequence from top to bottom without resorting to for loops which will be very slow to process on my large dataset?

Comment: What happens if `particular condition` is on the first row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `na.locf` in the zoo package:

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(replace(m, m == 2, NA))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1   32
[3,]    1 4351
[4,]    1    1
[5,]    3    4
[6,]    4    5
[7,]    5 6546
[8,]   67  456
```

**Note:** Data used:

```
m <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 67L, 1L, 32L, 4351L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 6546L, 456L), .Dim = c(8L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, NULL))
```

**Update** Revised to use `m` as shown.

Comment: AWESOME. I'll have a go at implementing this soon, but it looks like the perfect function. I wish I knew about it earlier :P Thank you good sir!